# How to download latest file from web archive, using powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I'd like a powershell script to download the most recent AMD64 installer from [web archive](https://repo.saltstack.com/windows/).

I have this, where the URL is hard-coded:

```
$src = 'https://repo.saltstack.com/windows/Salt-Minion-2015.8.5-AMD64-Setup.exe'
$dst = $env:temp+'\Salt-Minion-2015.8.5-AMD64-Setup.exe'

# Download installer
Invoke-WebRequest $src -OutFile $dst

# Install
& $dst /S /master=salt /minion-name=$env:computername /start-service=1

# Remove installer
Remove-Item $dst
```

How can I retrieve the latest installer and set `$src` to its URL?

I've figured out how to list all files and folders:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 'https://repo.saltstack.com/windows' | select -ExpandProperty Links | select href
```

The output:

```
...
...
...
Salt-Minion-2015.8.5-AMD64-Setup.exe
Salt-Minion-2015.8.5-AMD64-Setup.exe.md5
Salt-Minion-2015.8.5-x86-Setup.exe
Salt-Minion-2015.8.5-x86-Setup.exe.md5
archive/
dependencies/
```

...however, how do I extract the last file with `AMD64` and not `.md5` in the filename?

Comment: I would use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) to get the web page and find the last version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
# Find latest installer
$url = 'https://repo.saltstack.com/windows/'
$site = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $url
$table = $site.links | ?{ $_.tagName -eq 'A' -and $_.href.ToLower().Contains('amd64') -and $_.href.ToLower().EndsWith("exe") } | sort href -desc | select href -first 1
$filename = $table.href.ToString()

# Download installer
$src = $url + $filename
$dst = $env:temp + '\' + $filename
Invoke-WebRequest $src -OutFile $dst

# Install
& $dst /S /master=salt /minion-name=$env:computername /start-service=1
```

Comment: You are forwarding output with `>`. If removed that output would just be captured in the variable. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware of how to convert the object to string, but I worked it out: `$table.href.ToString()`